# Error when trying to put items from database into Listbox in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, nameerror

I'm fairly new to python and very new to Tkinter.  I am getting an error when trying to populate my listbox with data from my database.  The error is NameError: name 'listbox' is not defined -- I have included the function from my database and am having issues with my "populate customer list" function and then with my "listbox" not being defined.  Thanks in advance for help -- took a lot of code out but first time asking a question here.  Also realize I should prob be using classes but am in too deep :)  *Before I was getting this error, it was running but the listbox never populated with the data in my table*

Function from SQLite Database (just in case the issue lies here but this should work).  I'm calling this in my "populate list" function

```
    def fetch_customers(self):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM customers")
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()
        return rows
```

Code from my app (apologies for length)

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import messagebox
    from db import Database

    db = Database('store.db')


    def main_account_screen():
        global main_screen
        main_screen = Tk()
        main_screen.geometry("500x500")
        main_screen.title("Welcome")
        Label(text="Select From the Below", bg="powder blue", width="300",
              height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
        Label(text="").pack()
        Button(text="Customers", height="2", width="30",
               command=customers_page).pack()
        Label(text="").pack()
        Button(text="Products", height="2", width="30",
               command=products_page).pack()

        main_screen.mainloop()


    def customers_page():
        global customers_page_screen
        global customer_view
        global listbox
        customers_page_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
        customers_page_screen.title("Customers")
        customers_page_screen.geometry('1000x1000')
        Label(customers_page_screen, text="Customers Page", bg="powder blue", width="300",
              height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()

        # Entry boxes

        company_text = StringVar()
        Label(customers_page_screen,
              text="Company").pack()
        Entry(customers_page_screen, textvariable=company_text).pack()

        # Create Customer Information View
        **#PROBLEM AREA**

        listbox = Listbox(customers_page_screen, height=11, width=50,)
        listbox.pack()

        
    #PROBLEM AREA
    def populate_customer_list():
        global populate_customer_list
        for row in db.fetch_customers():
            listbox.insert(END, row)

    populate_customer_list()
```

Comment: You did not execute `customers_page()` before executing `populate_customer_list()`, so `listbox` has not been created.

Comment: I think you should execute `populate_customer_list()` at the end of `customers_page()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks!  executing populate_customer_list() inside of my customers_page() function worked.  Really appreciate your help